# AWS athena query string exceed maximum query length limit in engine Version 3

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

While migrating from Athena version 2 to version3, I've came acroess query length limit error. I know there are some ways to resolve this mentioned https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/athena-query-string-length however wanted to see if there are other alternatives.

I create query statement for each element in a list using python into

```
SELECT col_1, n_tile(4) over (order by col_1 asc), col_2, n_tile(4) over (order by col_2 asc), and so on....
```

So basically I am calcualting 4 quartiles for each col_{i}. Are there any ways to reduce query length?

I'm thinking of adding for loop in Athena query or trying ways to rename n_tile() operation into shorter name.

Comment: Is this really `order by col_x`, i.e. ordering by the same column which is used for partitioning?